# .ToString("N0") not working on ubuntu server but works on home PC

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

On a Discord bot I have made I am using the ToString("N0") function on some commands to convert numbers like 1000 to 1,000. When putting my bot onto my new server which is ubuntu 19.04 (the old one was 18.04.2) the numbers were not getting commas put in them and were just left how they are.  I thought maybe the ToString("N0") was broke so I tried using string.Format but that also did not work on the server but it works on my home PC. So I was wondering is there like a package I need to install that may not be installed to fix this?

I have tried using string.Format instead like I mentioned and I have also tried updating the packages and rebooting the server then re-running the bot but that did not fix it.

```cs
embed.AddField(y =>
{
   y.Name = "Score";
   y.Value = $"{Convert.ToInt32(stats.GetValue("credit")).ToString("N0")}";
   y.IsInline = true;
});
embed.AddField(y =>
{
   y.Name = "Completed WUs";
   y.Value = $"{Convert.ToInt32(stats.GetValue("wus")).ToString("N0")}";
   y.IsInline = true;
});
```

For example, say when stats.GetValue("credit") return 10000000 it should change it to 10,000,000 but the embed field has it as 10000000 when the message is sent but on my PC it adds the commas.

Comment: What is the culture of the new server? The ToString formatting options look at the currently running culture, so if the machine isn't set up with a culture which uses commas to separate numbers (i.e. 1,000), then the N0 will not produce the string that you want. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier) for more details.

Comment: I think it is C.UTF-8 so I think what I'll do is set the culture like the examples on that page showed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the culture info to the one I was using on my home PC solved this.

```
embed.AddField(y =>
{
   y.Name = "Score";
   y.Value = $"{Convert.ToInt32(stats.GetValue("credit")).ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))}";
   y.IsInline = true;
});
embed.AddField(y =>
{
   y.Name = "Completed WUs";
   y.Value = $"{Convert.ToInt32(stats.GetValue("wus")).ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))}";
   y.IsInline = true;
});
```